# How to check if a mail:inbound-channel-adapter in Spring Integration is running?

Tags: spring-integration

i'm using control-bus to start and stop a mail:inbound-channel-adapter in Spring Integration.
Is there any way to check the channel status? If it's running or not?

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 3):

Use a messaging gateway to send a message to the control bus...

```
public interface Gateway {
    boolean controlBusBooleanMethod(String command);
}

...

<int:gateway service-interface="foo.Gateway" default-request-channel="toControlBus" />

...

@Autowired
Gateway gateway;

...

boolean isRunning = gateway.controlBusBooleanMethod("@adapter.isRunning()");

....
```

HTH